# JQuery Find Data In Sibling Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with parent/child row relationships.

When the table opens, you will only see the parent (Totals) row.

[image: totals]

The details/child row are hidden

[image]

So, what I want to happen is to remove the "hide" class from the child rows (for the same ID) on click.

```
//Row click events
$('#table1').on('click','tbody tr', function (event) {
    var td = $('td', this);
    //Get the value in the second column
    var id = $(td[1]).text();

    //This doesn't work, but I need something like this
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').find(id).removeClass('hide');
}
```

I'm trying to find out how to write the script to check sibling rows for the same ID (as the row that was clicked) and remove the class on just those rows.

Comment: Give all the child rows a class that the parent is aware of, then just hide/show that class on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("table").find('td:contains('+id+')').closest('tr').removeClass("hide");
```

Comment: Awesome!  You got it.  It was a matter of syntax with the contains, which should use a semi colon.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. No `.` after `closest`. You might need to use `.contain()` this way:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("tr td:contains(" + id + ")").removeClass("hide");
```

Comment: The syntax mistake was because I retyped this without copy and paste.  I corrected the original.  Let me try this solution.

Comment: Not working for me.  I'm getitng this in FireBug.. `TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...).contains is not a function`

Comment: @madvora Did you add jQuery? `:P`

Comment: @madvora Can you please change `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: @Praveen your answer will return <td> hence it will not work, it should return <tr>

Comment: Contains needs a semi colon.  I accepted the working answer above.  Thanks

Comment: @madvora Would you like to add my answer?

Comment: @Praveen how can you ask to add your answer, I think it will not work still, because it will return <td> instead of <tr>

Answer (score 0):

give class names to each `tr` elements, this snippet may help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".child").hide(); //intially children are hidden

  $(".parent").click(function() {

    $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, o) {

      if ($(o).hasClass("child"))
        $(o).toggle();
      else
        return false;
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">

  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
    <th>four</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="parent">
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="parent">
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="parent">
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
    <td>child</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

ment with `parent` or

Comment: Good idea, but in my case I'm using JQuery DataTables and the data comes from an Ajax source.  The <tr> and <td> elements are created dynamically so I can't attach classes to the rows.